# Dividing each cell in a data set by the column sum in R with missing cells

Tags: r

I am trying to divide each cell in a data frame by the sum of the column. For example, I have a data frame df:

```
Company_Name Company_Location Area_code Fund_1  Fund_2 
A                 SGD          15         10     NA
B                 LDN          85         NA     4
C                 NY           54         3      NA
D                 SGD          15         NA     6
E                 LDN          85         4      5

dat <- structure(list(Company_Name = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), Company_Location = c("SGD", 
"LDN", "NY", "SGD", "LDN"), Area_code = c(15L, 85L, 54L, 15L, 
85L), Fund_1 = c(10L, NA, 3L, NA, 4L), Fund_2 = c(NA, 4L, NA, 
6L, 5L)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

I would like to create a new data frame that takes each cell in and divides by the sum of the column, like so:

```
Company_Name Company_Location Area_code Fund_1  Fund_2 
A                 SGD          15         0.588    NA
B                 LDN          85         NA      0.267
C                 NY           54         0.176    NA
D                 SGD          15         NA      0.400
E                 LDN          85         0.235   0.333
```

I tried the following without success.

```
DF <- apply(DF[,4:5],2,function(x){x/sum(x)})
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `sum` refuses to work du to the `NA`s, you need `na.rm=TRUE`.

```
apply(DF[, 4:5], 2, function(x) {x/sum(x, na.rm=TRUE)})
```

However, since R is vectorized, you may use `colSums`.

```
DF[4:5] <- DF[4:5] / colSums(DF[4:5], na.rm=TRUE)
DF
#   Company_Name Company_Location Area_code    Fund_1    Fund_2
# 1            A              SGD        15 0.5882353        NA
# 2            B              LDN        85        NA 0.2352941
# 3            C               NY        54 0.1764706        NA
# 4            D              SGD        15        NA 0.3529412
# 5            E              LDN        85 0.2352941 0.3333333
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a tidyverse solution:

```
mutate(dat, across(c("Fund_1", "Fund_2"), ~. / sum(., na.rm = TRUE)))
```